# Is it possible and how get all users from LDAP using python and django?

Tags: python, django, ldap, ldap-query

#### Env:

```
python - 3.6.6
django - 2.x.x
django-auth-ldap - 2.0.0         
python-ldap - 3.2.0
```

#### Code:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend, _LDAPUser, LDAPSearch

user = _LDAPUser(LDAPBackend(), "any")  # just for getting root connection to LDAP
search = LDAPSearch(
    "ou=Some,dc=some,dc=some,dc=some",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    "???? what should be here ???"  # criteria, I guess
)

# list of users is expected, or at least user's names
result = search.execute(user.connection)
```

#### Question:

How to construct correct criteria(or how it should be called correctly) for getting list of users? (links would be great)
Is it possible at all?

#### Solution(not for production, just working sketch):

```
# based on https://medium.com/@alpolishchuk/pagination-of-ldap-search-results-with-python-ldap-845de60b90d2
import ldap
from ldap.controls import SimplePagedResultsControl
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend, _LDAPUser


user = _LDAPUser(LDAPBackend(), "any")
connect = user.connection
page_control = SimplePagedResultsControl(True, size=2, cookie='')

result = []
fuse = 2
while True:
    fuse -= 1
    if fuse < 0:
        break
    response = connect.search_ext(
        "ou=some,dc=some,dc=some,dc=some",
        ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        "(objectClass=inetorgperson)",
        [],
        serverctrls=[page_control]
    )
    rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = connect.result3(response)
    result.extend(rdata)
    controls = [control for control in serverctrls
                if control.controlType == SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType]
    if not controls:
        print("The server ignores RFC 2696 control")
        break
    if not controls[0].cookie:
        break
    page_control.cookie = controls[0].cookie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different scenarios that may be involved in your environment.

- How many users in LDAP?
- Which LDAP server implementation? (Microsoft Active Directory?)
- You may need to use the [Simple Paged Results control](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control).

As for the Filter, there are [some examples](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches) for Microsoft Active Directory

For (NOT AD) something simple like

```
(objectClass=inetorgperson)
```

Should be sufficient.

Comment: Good questions! There is no information related to that :) Based on your answer I could assume, that my question is not correct, due to different implementations of LDAP and therefore different available search criteria.

Comment: Based on your clue - i found this article https://medium.com/@alpolishchuk/pagination-of-ldap-search-results-with-python-ldap-845de60b90d2  And I'll update my question with current solution